# Layout on phone & emulator quite different from designer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am trying out a simple layout exercise but am struggling to get even a simple layout to work.

In the designer it is as follows:

[image]

But when run, the output on an emulator or real phone is:

[image]

The Xml markup is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.hceng.myapplication.MainActivity"
 tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
 tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="E-mail:"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="52dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Me!"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="96dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="266dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="66dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am new to this markup language, but I thought it seems simple enough with absolute positioning throughout. In any case, the layout seen in the designer is what I want. Why is the above not working?

Comment: Every layout should have a ViewGroup such as LinearLayout, RelativeLayout if there are more than one View in your layout. So I guess you have not shown the whole content of layout file, Please show the whole code.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated with the complete layout file contents. If something else is needed, why doesn't the layout editor include it, or how is the designer able to show it correctly without it?

Comment: I am not familiar with ConstraintLayout. You can know it from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html

Comment: @OldGeezer try changing your parent layout from ConstraintLayout to linnerlayout or relativelayout

Comment: Thanks. Got it. It was added by the designer when I followed https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation

> When you drop a view into the Layout Editor, it stays where you leave it even if it has no constraints. However, this is only to make editing easier; if a view has no constraints when you run your layout on a device, it is drawn at position [0,0] (the top-left corner).

This is the reason why you see layout correctly in editor but not on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if not bound to **ConstraintLayout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.hceng.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email_tv"
        android:text="E-mail:" />

        <EditText   
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="266dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email_tv"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me!"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraint layout has some limitations but I am not sure if colour is one of them.

**First**

You could try changing the constraint layout to maybe coordinator layout or relative layout.

**If that fails**

Maybe, the target SDK version in your Android Manifest is too high, if the target version is higher than phone version, it reverts to defaults. So you could try doing placing a lower target version.